# Google Chrome update won't install due to unmet dependencies

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome, dependencies

There was an update for [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) today, and it wasn't installable due to unresolved dependencies. How can I correct this?

[image: Screenshot of Synaptic]

Comment: I have the same problem... but only lib32gcc1...

Comment: @lilicus I think that's because you have libxss1 installed

Comment: This was an issue with the Chrome repositories. The issue was fixed and solutions doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Download dummy packages:

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85403877/ubu13-chrome-fix/lib32gcc1_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85403877/ubu13-chrome-fix/lib32stdc%2B%2B6_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85403877/ubu13-chrome-fix/libc6-i386_2.17-0ubuntu5_all.deb
```

Then install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i lib32gcc1_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb lib32stdc++6_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb libc6-i386_2.17-0ubuntu5_all.deb
```

Then you can install Google Chrome:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Comment: Working for me. But it is not bad for future automatic updates of this packages?

Comment: Good question. But anyway these packages cannot be installed on 32-bit Ububntu in normal way so I think they won't be updated in normal way too.

Answer (score 8):

See, I am also having this problem, and I did a little research of my own to see what the issue was. Also, I have the same exact errors that were posted.

As it turns out, the Google Code Developers for 32-bit Ubuntu/Debian Google Chrome "made a goof," and accidentally added those dependencies which are of 64-bit architecture, and inaccessible by 32-bit Ubuntu/Debian. The 64-bit program is working fine, as it turned out.

All we can do is wait until another update comes out that will fix this issue; I am currently waiting patiently, using Chromium as my backup. Make sure to update/install when a new Google Chrome version is released as it will possibly--and hopefully--fix this issue.

If you can not wait, I have read that the unstable/beta version of Chrome does not have this issue as it was resolved during the development of this new version. [You can download it here.](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html)

I would only download that if you can not wait or use another browser until the stable update comes out.

source: [Google Chrome update won't install due to unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359530/google-chrome-update-wont-install-due-to-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable` doesn't work, try this: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html

Answer (score 4):

You have probably encountered this bug: [Wrong 64-bit dependencies on 32-bit version of Ubuntu](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304017). It's being worked on.

All I can suggest is that you keep watching that bug's progress and stay on your current version until it's well and truly fixed. There are a few comments there indicating that it's fixed but then [look at a more recent bug report which has been merged into #304017](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=307653), which is why I'm suggesting patience. If you wish, just `sudo` untick the Google Chrome ppa in your Software Sources for now. You can re-enable it whenever you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing exactly the same problem, on two different 32-bit 12.04 machines; see [Unable to select Chrome updates on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363280/unable-to-select-chrome-updates-on-ubuntu-12-04)

However, I can report that as of noon EST on 23 Oct 2013, the problem seems to be resolved for me.  The Chrome update could be selected, and it installed successfully.