# Unable to install google chrome in ubuntu12.04 via "google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb"

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, google-chrome

After typing the command `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome stable_current_i386.deb` the following error occurs:

```
 sandeep@sandeep-pc:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb 
 Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.                                                                              
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 143783 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1); however:
  Package lib32gcc1 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Package lib32stdc++6 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.11); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
  google-chrome-stable
```

How can I install Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Update won't install due to unmet dependencies](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359530/google-chrome-update-wont-install-due-to-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Hi Sandeep, welcome to AskUbuntu. Do you have any particular reason to prefer Chrome over Chromium? The latter can be easily installed from the Software Centre.

Answer (score 1):

Just double tap on google-chrome- stable.deb and wait until the ubuntu softeware center is open then click on install this method is better than " dpkg " and works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You should install the unmet dependencies, using `sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libc6-i386` But if Ubuntu refuses to do the install, it is a true dependency problem and you should seek an alternative to Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

To install Chrome using PPA.

Add Key:
`wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -`

Set repository:
`echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`

Install package:
`sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

Or else, you can try the opensource web application I built 
[www.ins2all.com?a=Chrome](http://www.ins2all.com?a=Chrome)

It generates a bash script with the steps for installing selected applications.

> You must also run
>
> `sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 libc6-i38`
>
> for fixing unmet dependencies. 'lib32gcc1', 'lib32stdc++6' and 'libc6-i38' are missing here according the question.

Comment: Why are all your answers variations on "go to this web sight"? - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/790355)

Comment: I built it. I thought giving a link will help solve the problem.

Comment: Five answers essentially identical with two that are exactly identical is in my opinion spam. Also you hadn't relieved that you were the author. Directing inexperienced users to go download a script that they might not be able to understand whether any of the commands could be harmful is suspect. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259)

Comment: Yeah. Updated the answer.