# Unable to select Chrome updates on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, google-chrome, update-manager, repository

I own two machines, both of which are running Ubuntu 12.04.  I use Google Chrome on both.

A Google Chrome update is available, and it appears in the Update Manager.  However, I cannot select the update.  There is a check box beside the name of the update but I cannot check it, no matter what I do.

This error occurs on both machines.

Updates from the usual repositories (e.g. Canonical) work fine.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

The repository I am using for Chrome updates is **dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/**

Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that this issue exists (and started recently for me) on Ubuntu 13.10 as well.

Comment: I seems like the depends for google-chrome-stable are different in version: **30.0.1599.101-1**

Comment: best answer at [Google Chrome Update won't install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359530/google-chrome-update-wont-install-due-to-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: As of noon Eastern Standard Time on 23 Oct, the problem for me seems to be resolved.  (Thank you Andreas and Gregor for confirming and explaining the source of the problem.)